# Two Isotrivial Minimal Elliptic Surfaces with the Same Singular Fibres

Tags: algebraic-geometry

An Elliptic surface of constant modular function $\mathbb{J}$ is called isotrivial.

Two Isotrivial Minimal Elliptic Surfaces over $\mathbb{P}^1$ have the Same Singular Fibres,

Are they isomorphic as elliptic surfaces?

I believe so, where I can find a good reference ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to dig out this old question. I think the classical reference is Kodaira, On Complex Analytic Surfaces II (in general the sequence of articles On Compact Complex Analytic Surfaces I,II,III and On the **Structure** of Compact Analytic Surfaces I) where Kodaira describe all elliptic surfaces.

If I've correctly understood the principal facts of his huge work, there are three principal propositions. Given a base $N$ (compact complex smooth curve) the functionnal (modular) invariant $\mathbb{J}: N \longrightarrow \mathbb{H}/SL_2$ and the homological invariant $\mathcal{G}$ (a sheaf over the base $N$ obtained as the extension of the local system corresponding to the monodromy of $\tilde{\omega}:\tilde{N\setminus \text{singular fibers}} \longrightarrow \mathbb{H}$ such that $\mathbb{J}=j\circ \tilde{\omega}$).

1. There is a unique (up to isomorphisms of elliptic surfaces) $B\overset{\pi_0}{\longrightarrow} N$ (the \textit{basic member})  elliptic surface with base $N$, homological and functional invariants $(\mathbb{J},\mathcal{G})$ and with a global holomorphic section.
2. Any $M'\overset{\pi'}{\longrightarrow} N$ with the same invariants and with only simple singular fibers (in particular there is a section in a neighborhood of any singular point) is obtained by gluing parts of $B$ with a cocyle of automorphisms of $B$
3. Any $M\overset{\pi}{\longrightarrow} N$ with the same invariants is bimeromorphic to $M'$ as in 2., through a transformation called a *logarithmic transformation*

Now, we can consider $B=\mathbb{P}_1 \times \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ the trivial principal elliptic bundle, which is the basic member for $\mathbb{J}$ constant and $\mathcal{G}$ the trivial sheaf (since it has a global section and no singular fiber).
It is isotrivial in the sense of your definition.

But there is also the classical Hopf surface $M\overset{\pi}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{P}^1$ which is a nontrivial principal elliptic bundle.

So I would say that the statement is not true in general?